# How do I set the duration of a "calendar insert" in tasker

Tags: tasker

Declaring the starting time to be now seems to be easy in tasker. I just put 0 into the "In / For(Minutes)" field. However how do I define the length of the calendar event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `In / For` field actually serves both purposes. You can enter two numbers, delimited by a `/` such that:

- The first number is the number of minutes from now when the event starts, and
- The second number is the duration of the event

If you wanted to insert a one hour event starting "now", you would, for example, set the value of the field to `0 / 60`.

This is summarized from the "Calendar Insert" entry in [Tasker's Action documentation](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html).